# Создание адаптивного меню навигации в сетку 2×2

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, css-grid

У меня есть навигационное меню которое надо сделать адаптивным
Само меню состоит из 4 кнопок, и мне нужно что бы они перестраивались в сетку 2 на 2
Так же присутствуют отступы
Слева и справа = 30%
Сверху 1em
Первый раз приходится создавать такое меню[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что, правда есть меню? Пока не покажете - не поверим.

Comment: Отредактировал, теперь верите?

Comment: 2 * 2, а есть макет с такой сеткой?

Comment: Не понял суть вопроса